# PyTorch grid_sample returns zero array

Tags: pytorch

I want to sample rectangular patch from my image by `affine_grid`/`grid_sample`
I created array which contains only `255` values

```
canvas1 = np.zeros((128, 128), dtype=np.uint8)
canvas1[:] = 255
```

Also i created grid

```
theta = torch.FloatTensor([[
    [11/2, 0, 63],
    [0, 11/2, 63],
]])
grid = F.affine_grid(theta, (1, 1, 11, 11))
```

Grid contains values like

```
     [[57.5000, 57.5000],
      [58.6000, 57.5000],
      [59.7000, 57.5000],
      [60.8000, 57.5000],
      [61.9000, 57.5000],
      [63.0000, 57.5000],
      [64.1000, 57.5000],
      [65.2000, 57.5000],
      [66.3000, 57.5000],
      [67.4000, 57.5000],
      [68.5000, 57.5000]],
...............
```

After that i called grid_sample

```
canvas1_torch = torch.FloatTensor(canvas1.astype(np.float32))
canvas1_torch = canvas1_torch.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
sampled = F.grid_sample(canvas1_torch, grid, mode="bilinear")
```

Unfortunately `sampled` contains zero values (but `canvas1_torch[0, 0, 63, 65]`) is 255

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid values are outside [-1, 1].

According to https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.grid_sample, such values are handled as defined by `padding_mode`.

Default `padding_mode` is 'zeros', what you probably want is "border": `F.grid_sample(canvas1_torch, grid, mode="bilinear", padding_mode="border")` returns all values 255.